# Converting Numeric to timestamp format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have numeric data in a field and need to convert it to timestamp as like below. Please help on this.

source data:
20220929121001.0000000
20220919085939.0000000

need to convert to below format of timestamp:
yyyymmddhh24miss

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
select to_timestamp_ntz(to_char(20220929121001.0000000),'yyyymmddhh24miss') tstmp
```

`to_char` - to convert to char and remove training 0s.
`to_timestamp_ntz` - to convert char to timestamp

You can also try to wrap around to_number() to remove 0s like below.

```
select to_timestamp_ntz(to_char(to_number( 20220929121001.0000000)),'yyyymmddhh24miss') tstmp
```

[image: sc]

Comment: getting below error, looks like it is not removing 0's

`Can't parse '0.0000000' as timestamp with format 'yyyymmddhh24miss' `

Comment: i attached screenshot from my SF. Anyways, you can wrap around with to_number() to remove 0s.

Comment: Thank you :), i commented the logic , did trunc to remove zero's

Answer (score 0):

I am able to convert by doing following logic 
`TO_VARCHAR(to_timestamp(to_char(trunc(20220929121001.0000000)),'yyyymmddhh24miss'),'yyyymmddhh24miss')`

Comment: You did not mention what data type you want as output. I assumed output will be timestamp. Pls add more clarity to the qn.